# MeteorJS REST API from External URL (using CollectionsFS)

Tags: javascript, meteor, cors

We've implemented an API using CollectionFS' http-methods package (https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-methods)

However, this API needs to be called from another (external) domain, which means our API Server must respond to a preflight OPTIONS methods and have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set to either * or the external domain.

Unfortunately, while the Internet if filled with various suggestions, mainly for Meteor's mobile app/cordova support. I could not find a working solution when trying to access an API endpoint via an external domain.

Any suggestions?

P.S - Please avoid suggestions that hit on NOT implementing an API and using DDP instead, as they are not relevant in this case.

Comment: Have you tried `this.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://your.domain.com")` in the method body?

Comment: Yes, does not make a difference

Comment: This is strange. This will probably require more information. Did you check if the header is sent? Are you able to create another (custom) header? Perhaps the issue is different.

Comment: I just tested this again and I am able to receive the desired header.

Comment: Thanks @MasterAM - your were/are right!

Comment: Great. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package allows setting headers using `this.addHeader(name, value)` in the method body.

By default, there is an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set for Cordova (`"http://meteor.local"`), and adding such header will replace it.

So, setting `this.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://your.domain.com")` will allow `http://your.domain.com` to call the API.