# How to allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin on meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, cors

My problem is the following:

I've created a `HTTP.method` using `cfs:http-methods` and the problem is that I can't make it to receive the post from other client...

I'm using [this site](http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client#?client_method=POST&client_credentials=false&server_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.easydelivery.net.br%2FpagseguroNotifications&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote) to test cors, and the error is the following:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.easydelivery.net.br/pagseguroNotifications.
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://meteor.local'
that is not equal to the supplied origin.
Origin 'http://client.cors-api.appspot.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My method is still simple, I want to be abble to connect first to finish it so here it is:

```
HTTP.methods({
  '/pagseguroNotifications': function() {
    console.log(this.request);
  }
});

Meteor.startup(function() {
  // Listen to incoming HTTP requests, can only be used on the server
    console.log('chamou');
  WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return next();
  });
});
```

Comment: just checked http://www.easydelivery.net.br/pagseguroNotifications and it is sending `access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type`
`access-control-allow-methods: PUT`
`access-control-allow-origin: http://meteor.local`

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33461180/268093) solve the problem?

Comment: i don't know why but it is working now uahhusahu